# how to check specific word like "add" and do specific job in C

Tags: c

```
void repl(){
  while(1){
    while(words[a]!='\0'){
       if(isNumeric(words[a])){
          push(words[a]);
       }else if(strcmp(words[a],"add")==0){
          strcpy(value1, pop());
          strcpy(value2, pop());
          sum2 = (int)atoi(value1) + (int)atoi(value2);
          itoa(sum2,sum);
          printf("%d",sum2);
        }
        a++;
        if(words[a] == '\0'){
          printStack();
    }
}
```

what I need to care about this code is to receive numbers as char temp[] and check them that they are numeric or not.

however I succeed that part of thing, but what I need to solve now is to check if the words[a] is add

then pop last 2 value to calculate sum of them and push back sum into stack.

while I did on this code I received segmentation fault

```
repl>1 2 3 4
4 
3
2 
1
repl>add
Segmentation fault
```

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: can you more specific error info & the code related to pop

Comment: `words` is an array of chars or an array of pointers to char? either way `words[a]!='\0'` is wrong or `strcmp(words[a],"add")` is wrong